# PHP - check if multiple radios are selected and then go to other php

Tags: php, html, validation

I have a form containing 36 radio button selection sections. These are being generated from an SQL query:

```
//sql query
<form method="post" action="next.php">
<table border=1><tr><td>ID</td>selection</td></tr>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$row["ID"]."\" value=\"1\">1<input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$row["ID"]."\" value=\"X\">X<input type=\"radio\" name=\"".$row["ID"]."\" value=\"2\">2</td></tr>";
    }
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></table></form>
```

So, the name of each radio section is the `ID` from the query. When the user clicks on the `Submit` button I need all the radios are set (loop through them). If not, then I want to show an error but keeping the user on the same page without loosing all the selections he made already. If all radios are set, then go to `next.php` where I will process the stuff from `$_POST`.

Comment: Why don't you use checkboxes and an array as name?

Comment: Why not add a `required="required"` attribute to your radios? That should probably be enough?

Comment: @putvande OMG. I'm a complete moron. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned by @putvande](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917003/php-check-if-multiple-radios-are-selected-and-then-go-to-other-php#comment61396229_36917003) in the comments, the problem can be solved by putting a `required="required"` attribute on the radio inputs.